# SPOnline : Folder alert for multiples users without 'control total' access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, permissions, alert, item-level-permissions

How can I allow my users to Create a complete alert (where you can set a list to send) without giving the Control Total?

They are in the "`Contribute" group but It allows them only to alert them-self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By default,** The Users with `contribute` permission Levels can only Create Alert but they can't `Manage Alerts  -  Manage alerts for all users of the Web site.`

**To allow the Contributors users to Manage alerts, you should do the following:**

- Go to Site Setting > `Users and Permissions` > `Site Permissions`.
- From the above ribbon, Click on `Permission Levels`.

[image]

- Click on `Contribute`.

[image]

- Below site permission, Check `Manage Alerts` as shown below

[image]

---

> **Note:** you can copy the `Contribute` Permission level to build and customize your own permission level, then use the customized
>   permission level as you prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I admire your you a lot for using this plateforme.